# Explicit Type Conversion in Remix

Tags: type-conversion, typeerror, solidity, contract, remix

This function:

```
  function initializeDomainSeparator() public {
    // hash the name context with the contract address
    EIP712_DOMAIN_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(// solium-disable-line
            EIP712_DOMAIN_SEPARATOR_SCHEMA_HASH,
            keccak256(bytes(name)),
            bytes32(address(this))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ));
}
```

Is kicking back this error:

```
TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "address" to "bytes32".
```

What am I doing wrong? pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Solidity 0.8.0 you can no longer convert `address` directly to `bytes32`. You have to perform two separate conversions: first to `bytes20`, which changes the type from `address` to fixed bytes and only then to `bytes32` which extends the length.

See [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes > New Restrictions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html#new-restrictions)

> There are new restrictions on explicit type conversions. The conversion is only allowed when there is at most one change in sign, width or type-category (`int`, `address`, `bytesNN`, etc.). To perform multiple changes, use multiple conversions.

> - `address(uint)` and `uint(address)`: converting both type-category and width. Replace this by `address(uint160(uint))` and `uint(uint160(address))` respectively.

So the correct conversion in your case would be `bytes32(bytes20(address(this)))`.

But `abi.encodePacked()` does not require the argument to be of a bytes type and in fact you do not need a conversion here at all:

```solidity
EIP712_DOMAIN_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(// solium-disable-line
    EIP712_DOMAIN_SEPARATOR_SCHEMA_HASH,
    keccak256(bytes(name)),
    this
));
```

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem, please remember to mark it as a solution to the question :)